# Find all possible arrays of size n constructed with all possible combinations of elements from another array in all possible orders?

Tags: c++, c, combinatorics

For an array A of arbitrary length n, I'd like to fill in a n x m array B with all combination of elements from A that includes all possible orders of those elements. For example, if A = {1, 2, 3} and m = 2, I'd like to get B as:

11

12

13

21

22

23

31

32

33

What is an efficient way to do this in C/C++? Thanks!

EDIT: Here is what I figured out to work (data is within the class combs which is basically a matrix class with some added tricks):

```
void combs::setCombs (int arr[], int n, int m) {
    int z, tmp, repeat;
        int max = (int (pow(double (n), double( m ))));
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                z = 0;
                repeat = int (pow( double (n), double (i)));
                for (int j = 0; j < repeat; j++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < n; k ++) {
                                for (int p = 0; p < max/(n*repeat); p ++) {
                                        cout << arr[k] << endl;
                                        data[z*ROWS + i] = arr[k];
                                        z++;
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried? What worked? What didn't work? What problems have you encountered? Have you read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)?

Comment: @rightfold I compile with g++, so C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
void printStrRec(string s,string ans,int k,int i)
{
    if(i==k)
    {
        cout<<"\nAnswer : "<<ans<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int x=0;x<s.size();++x)
        {
            ans[i]=s[x];
            printStrRec(s,ans,k,i+1);
        }
    }
}
void printStrings(string s,int k)
{
    string ans;
    for(int p=0;p<k;++p)
    {
        ans+="x";
    }
    printStrRec(s,ans,k,0);
}
int main()
{
    int k;
    string s;
    cout<<"Enter the set : ";
    cin>>s;
    cout<<"\nEnter k : ";
    cin>>k;
    printStrings(s,k);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is what I was doing originally, but it's not what I actually want. This would print 123 but not 321.

Comment: It works for all 'm'(be it less than, equal to or greater than 'n')

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Joachim Pileborg your question lacks a lot in the way of parameters.
But lets say you could guarantee that you were passing me a vector of SORTED UNIQUE ints. Then this brute force would be possible:

```
std::vector< std::string > Combo( const std::vector< char >& source, int m )
{
    std::vector< std::vector< char >::const_iterator > digits( length, source.cbegin() );
    std::vector< std::string > result( source.size() * m );

    for( int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++ )
    { 

        for( int j = 0; j < m; j++ )
        {
            result[i] += *(digits[j]);
        }

        for( int j = digits.size() - 1; j >= 0; j-- )
        {
            ++digits[j];

            if( digits[j] == source.cend() )
            {
                digits[j] = source.cbegin();
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like partial permutations, not combinations.

If you are using c++, then it is recommended to use vectors, because vectors can tell you their size, and they free their own memory. An implementation with vectors would be as follows:

```
vector<vector<int> > partialPermutations(vector<int> &A,int m){
    int i,i2,t,n=A.size(),total=1;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++) total*=n;
    vector<vector<int> > result;
    for(i=0;i<total;i++){
        result.push_back(vector<int>());
        t=i;
        for(i2=0;i2<m;i2++){
            result[i].push_back(A[t%n]);
            t/=n;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> A;
    int total,i,i2;
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++) A.push_back(i);
    vector<vector<int> > re=partialPermutations(A,2);
    for(i=0;i<re.size();i++){
        for(i2=0;i2<2;i2++)
            cout<<re[i][i2]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you still want to use arrays, then the code would be as follows:

```
int** partialPermutations(int*A,int n,int m,int &total){
    int i,i2,t;
    total=1;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++) total*=n;
    int **result=new int*[total];
    for(i=0;i<total;i++){
        t=i;
        result[i]=new int[m];
        for(i2=0;i2<m;i2++){
            result[i][i2]=A[t%n];
            t/=n;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int A[]={1,2,3,4};
    int total,i,i2;
    int **re=partialPermutations(A,4,2,total);
    for(i=0;i<total;i++){
        for(i2=0;i2<2;i2++)
            cout<<re[i][i2]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    //Cleanup
    for(i=0;i<total;i++) delete[] re[i];
    delete[] re;
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that by using arrays, we have to recover the size of the resulting array (passing `total` by reference), and we have to free the memory afterwards. None of this is needed with vectors.